# List to json conversion javascript

Tags: javascript, json, list

Let's say I have two lists

```
a= ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
b= ['red', 'orange', 'yellow']
```

How can I convert it to a JSON object, using a second list as a guide for the attribute names?

For example, I would define attributes = `['fruit', 'color']`

in order to get

```
result = [
  {fruit: 'apple', color: 'red'}, 
  {fruit: 'orange', color: 'orange'}, 
  {fruit: 'banana', color: 'yellow'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use a library like underscore or lodash (or recreate the methods used here) it can be done like so:

```
var attributes = ['fruit', 'color'];
var fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'];

//Combine arrays in to list of pairs 
//(this would be expanded with each new array of attribute values)
//ORDER IS IMPORTANT
var zipped = _.zip(fruits, colors);

//Map the zipped list, returning an object based on the keys. 
//Remember the order of the arrays in the zip operation 
//must match the order of the attributes in the attributes list
var result = _.map(zipped, function(item, index) {
    return _.object(attributes, item);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've create one that accept 2 arguments, first is `array` as attributes, second is `array` of `array` as list items, and it'll handle if attribute number is more then given property items:

```js
 var create = function(attrList, propertyLists) {
  var result = [];
  var aLen = attrList.length;
  var pLen = propertyLists.length;
  
  if (pLen === 0) {
    return result;
  }

  var itemLength = propertyLists[0].length;
  if (itemLength === 0) {
    return result;
  }

  var i, j, obj, key;
  for (i = 0; i < itemLength; ++i) {
    obj = {};
    for(j = 0; j < aLen; ++j) {
      key = attrList[j];
      if (typeof propertyLists[j] === 'undefined') {
        //
        continue;
      }
      obj[key] = propertyLists[j][i];
    }
    result.push(obj);
  }

  return result;
 };

var a = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
var b= ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'];
var attrs = ['fruit', 'color'];
var jsonObj = create(attrs, [a, b]);
console.log(jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both lists are the same size and everything matches up this should work. However if they are not the same size this will break. What is your data like?

```
\\given
a= ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
b= ['red', 'orange', 'yellow']
attributes = ['fruit', 'color']

\\insert this code
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
    result.push({
        attributes[0]:a[i], 
        attributes[1]:b[i]
    });
}

console.log(result);
\\  result = [
\\      {fruit: 'apple', color: 'red'}, 
\\      {fruit: 'orange', color: 'orange'}, 
\\      {fruit: 'banana', color: 'yellow'}]
```

Comment: You should initialize result with the var/let statement, in order to avoid creating a global. `var result = [];`