# Create object with String index of two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, union

I have two arrays 
`data=[100,200,300];`
`inde=[one, two, three];`

I want to union this arrays in a object like this:

`obj=[{"label":"one","value"=100},
{"label":"two","value"=200},
{"label":"three","value"=300}];`

I'm starting with javascript and I can't do it dynamically

Comment: Will they always be the same length ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [List to json conversion javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275087/list-to-json-conversion-javascript/31275396#31275396).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = [];
for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++){
    var temp = {
        label: inde[i],
        value: data[i]
    };
    obj.push(temp);
}
```

Comment: Also, be sure to the strings in the inde array are enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` and `inde` will be the same length you can use sth like this

```
var data=[100,200,300]; var inde=['one', 'two', 'three'];   
var obj=[];
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var tmp={
        label:inde[i],
        value:data[i]
    }
    obj.push(tmp);
}
```